# Reverse for '' with arguments and keyword arguments '' not found

Tags: django, httpresponse, reverse

I have following views in my light_shop app:

```
def order_list(request, error_message):
    context = {}
    context['type'] = 'order-list'
    context['error_message'] = error_message
    update_context(request, context, add_order_list=True)
    return render(request, 'light_shop/order_list.html', context)

def add_to_list(request, prd_id):
    add_product_to_list(request, prd_id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('light_shop.views.order_list', args=('test_error',)))
```

and this is urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('light_shop',
    ...
    url(r'^add-to-list/(?P<prd_id>\d+)/$', 'views.add_to_list'),
    url(r'^show-list/()$', 'views.order_list'),
    ...
```

)

but I get error: `Reverse for 'light_shop.views.order_list' with arguments '('test_error',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` in add_to_list second line.

I even test naming parameter in url pattern for order_list. (e.g. `url(r'^show-list/(?P<error_message>)$', 'views.order_list')` and changing reverse function to `reverse('light_shop.views.order_list', kwargs={'error_message':'error_message'})`) but again same error is occurred.

I'm using Django 1.5 and I look this page for documantation and I am really confused what is the problem:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the URL pattern

```
url(r'^show-list/()$', 'views.order_list'),
```

which seems to be incomplete.

Update it to (Basically, specify a [`Named Group`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups))

```
url(r'^show-list/(?P<error_message>[\w_-]+)$', 'views.order_list'),
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. You beat me to this one. You may have one the battle, but the war aint over yet! :P

Comment: @karthikr Accepted. also one more question I'm not sure to ask it here in the comments. Is it a good idea to pass data between views using arguments in url? is there better way (e.g. POST method) along using reverse function?

Comment: Yeah.. a form post i guess would be the cleanest way. But too hard to comment without looking at the usecase

Comment: @karthikr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657564/best-way-to-pass-data-between-views-using-httpresponseredirect-and-reverse-fun